# Liferay Log Utilty

Tags: logging, plugins, liferay

I'm searching for a solution, here is my problem,
I want to develop a log utility system using Liferay extension environment(or maybe liferay portlet) as a new plugin.
There are various portlets in our portal which each of them has a database search capability in its form,
I would like to implement a feature to log user's action(specially search queries) during  their session ,
How can I implement  this feature as a standalone deployable plugin which does not impose a lot of changes in our portlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Message Bus framework: in every portlet you have to insert custom code to send a message of what happens.

You have to build a new plugin with message bus listener that collects every message and log it.

Comment: Liferay 6.0 introduce message bus, it's present. Why you can't use it?